# Choose automatically between two different policies in WS-SecurityPolicy

Tags: java, web-services, ws-security

I would like to write an Optional policy for a web service using the WS-SecurityPolicy specifications, for example if the client has a certificate it can sign the Soap Header but if it doesn't it can always use the web service with signature.

Any Idea ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Policy alternatives are made for this purpose. You can specify two different alternatives in your policy and then a client can choose the policy it wants to use. Here is an example:

```
<wsp:Policy ...>
  <wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All> 
      <!-- SecurityPolicy assertions for signing go here, e.g.: -->
      <sp:SignedParts ...>
         <sp:Header ... />
      </sp:SignedParts>
    </wsp:All> 
    <wsp:All>
      <!-- Policy alternatives may also be empty -->
   </wsp:All>
  </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

The client can choose exactly one of the two alternatives encapsulated by `<wsp:All />`. So in this case it can sign the header, but it does not have to. For more information, see [the WS-Policy Specification on Policy Alternatives](http://www.w3.org/Submission/WS-Policy/#Policy_Alternative).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, Actually i tested this solution, the expectation from my sided was, that one of the alternatives is choosen based on the actual request. But per default the alternative with the lowest number of assertions is chosen without taking the actual request into account. 
Then this selected alternative (effective Policy) is always used for all subsequent requests. 

Is this correct, or did I miss something? Is there a switch to change this behavior?

Comment: There is no standard rule for that. Which policy the client chooses and how it selects it is up to the runtime of the client or whatever you program it to. This is where things get tricky ;) It's highly runtime specific. What WS-Stack is your client using?

Comment: Actually i am using Apache-CXF, I found that CXF is configured to select the minimal declared policy by default but i still searching for an option to change it .

Comment: I'm not an expert on using policies with CXF, but it seems that you have to hook into their [policy engine](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-it-works.html). Maybe [this blog entry](http://ashakirin.blogspot.de/2012/02/using-ws-policy-in-cxf-projects.html) helps?